# Exception:duplicate entry: android/support/v7/widget/CardViewApi21.class

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hello i am facing this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/widget/CardViewApi21.class
```

i am remove duplicate dependencies,lib.

gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
//compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile project(':FacebookSDK')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
//compile files('libs/cardview-v7-21.0.0.jar')
 }

android {
compileSdkVersion 16
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("demo.jks")
        storePassword "demo"
        keyAlias "demo"
        keyPassword "demo"
    }
}

dexOptions {
    //incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
        }
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
  }
  }
 apply plugin: 'announce'
```

Comment: add `build.gradle` file. it's problem with dependencies section

Comment: Could you post your `build.gradle`?

Comment: hi any about idea??

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile your cardview like that

```
compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1') {
exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
```

Comment: post you gradle?/

Comment: plz check i m post in ans

Comment: you can try the 21.0.3 with latest version like 24.1.1 and and also compileSdkVersion with latest 24 or 23 . Set the also  defaultConfig {
           minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }

And also buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" with also latest 24.0.1 or other 


also Try to Update Android Support Lib. support lib to skd manager

Answer (score 0):

Remove unused jars from lib folder.
Clean the project and try to re-compile.

Also set the compileToolVersion to 23.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a jar file called `cardview-v7-21.0.0.jar`.

It is commented

```
//compile files('libs/cardview-v7-21.0.0.jar').
```

but using this line

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

you are just including the same jar file.

You **should delete** the `cardview-v7-21.0.0.jar` file from your `libs` folder.